# TypeCoverter and ContentProperty in same class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement my custom control, of `UIElement` type.
I would like to implement type converter of one of the control properties, which is the direct content of the control (like in `ContentControl`).

I know, that for support the direct content I have to use `ContentPropertyAttribute`, I also have a `TypeConverter` and my own type for the direct content property.

So - it looks like this:

XAML:

```
<controls:MyControl>    
<![CDATA[
Typical string to convert.
]]>
<controls:MyControl>
```

MyControl:

```
[ContentProperty("MyProperty")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
public class MyControl : UIElement
{
    public MyType MyProperty
    {
        get { return (MyType)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(MyType), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

I hope implementation of `MyTypeConverter` and `MyType` are not important here.

The problem is that, when I am trying to compile the code, I have an error:

```
error MC3090: TypeConverter syntax error encountered while processing initialization string '
error MC3090:     Typical string to convert.
error MC3090:     '.  Element attributes are not allowed on objects created via TypeConverter. Line 52 Position 8.
```

Obviously, my project is not working.
Is there any chance to implement it that way? Or maybe I have to change my approach?
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I was trying that option, but WPF doesn't know the type converter is applied for MyProperty and returning another error:

Comment: I was trying that option, but WPF doesn't know the type converter is applied for MyProperty and returning another error:

error MC3061: The Element type 'Namespace.MyControl' does not have an associated TypeConverter to parse the string '
error MC3061:                 Typical string to convert.
error MC3061:                 '. Line 49 Position 40.